# Get Mail Delegate Report in your Domain

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to know if there is any App script through which i can get mail delegate report of any mailbox in my Domain. I do have admin access to my domain.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: What do you mean by "delegate?"  You can use the advanced services [Admin SDK Directory Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory) to get information about devices, groups, users, and other entities in your domain.  Here is the quickstart to list all users in your domain.  [Link to Admin quickstart](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/apps-script)